# Error while installing Oracle Database 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, installation, windows-7-x64

I have windows 7 professional and I am trying to install Oracle database 11g on it.
I am getting this error every timer I try to run the setup.exe.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It was caused by an incomplete download. Check the size of your download on OTN web site.